# Gridview, and that pesky browser back button

Tags: asp.net, gridview, postback

Our ASP.NET page has a GridView on it with some data, and one column has CheckBoxes in order to select rows. A Delete button exists below the GridView. When the end user selects some items via the CheckBoxes and then clicks the Delete button, a postback fires, and deletes the selected items. Pretty common stuff.

The problem I've been assigned is also common. If, on the resulting page, the end user clicks the browser back-button, then (after a warning which is always summarily disregarded) the post-back re-initiates.

The problem here is that, since the selected items have already been deleted, the browser simply selects whatever rows now occupy the space where the deleted item once was, and proceeds to delete those items instead. This a Bad Thing™.

So far I've been banging around some ideas based around setting and checking Session variables to try and track if a postback has occurred, but I'm not too happy with the results yet.

Does anyone have a good (and hopefully simple) way of dealing with this issue?

Comment: Does this page use the Session to store the checked items that a user's about to delete? Or, are you saying that, after posting deleted items, the browser is (somehow) re-checking checkboxes at indices that no longer match the appropriate items? I'm not exactly clear on the cause of the re-selected checkboxes.

Comment: Sorry, getting back this question slowly as something else has taken precedence. No session values are being used for this. The checkboxes are checked and then submitted - standard asp.net stuff. So in this case, let's say I have 5 rows, check the first two, and submit. The first two rows are deleted. The remaining rows now "move up" in the grid, so what was previously rows 3-4 are now rows 1-2. The clicks the back button, and so the submit again takes place. The form values still indicate that rows 1-2 should be deleted, and so it does. There is now only 1 row left (in this example).

Comment: So, you're using a full postback via a `type="submit"` button? Can you post some relevant markup snippets and the submission C#/VB code as well?

Answer (score 0):

How about doing the deletion of records in GridView Asynchronously? (using an Updatepanel)

This will prevent the browser to save the selected checkboxes in Browser Cache and removes the annoying security popup browser checking whenever the user refreshes the page after a Full Postback.

Or by any chance, have you tried unchecking all the checkboxes in code-behind after the first binding? (let's say on Page_Load)

try this:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel id="upGv" runat="server" ChildrenAsTriggers="false" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:GridView ID="gv" runat="server" />
        <asp:Button ID="btnDelete" runat="server" Text="Delete" />
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

in code-behind:

```
Private Sub btnDelete_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnDelete.Click
    ' do a for loop searching for selected checkboxes and do the deleting here
    ' --- delete codes ---
    ' rebind the data in gridview
    gv.DataSource = 'some dataset/datatable etc etc
    gv.DataBind()
    'update the updatepanel
    upGv.Update()
End Sub
```

Comment: I had the same idea, but I think you cannot do trigger an asynchronous postback within a repeatable control... probably a matter of generated ids. Asynchronous is still the solution, but you will have to wrap-it under a bunch of JS : Get all checked item, extract the Id's, pass them to a web service, update the updatepanel

Comment: @Steve B - The postback would be triggered by the delete button below the grid, not by the grid itself - updatepanel is a viable solution. Question is, does the OP want the added complication, noise and page-weight associated with using MS Ajax libraries and partial-postbacks?

Comment: you are right, it's not a control nested in the gridview, but a control outside... which shouldn't be an issue ^-^. And your remark is right... Ajax isn't shipped with aspirin

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is an easy way.

You can play around with javascript and try various http browser cache settings but you can't really rely on any of it. You have to assume a user is going to be able to re-post the form.

I think you're right to deal with it in server code. How about this :

Create a cookie/session variable in the GET of the grid page.
Invalidate that cookie/session variable in the POST of the grid page.

This way when re-POSTed via the back button, your code should detect there's no valid cookie/session value and could then re-issue a redirect to the same page forcing a GET.

PRG Pattern.

It sounds like you are already using a Post-Redirect-Get pattern as you mention "a resulting page" from the postback. If you're not then this helps with the other problem of users pressing F5 on a posted form.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You could also put some value into viewstate along with session on the first !IsPostback and then change it to something else in the IsPostback.

This might be easier than cookies or browser cache expiration stuff.

In this case, if the user clicks the back button and submits anything, you can look at viewstate and see of it matches the value in session, if not then banish the user for eternity.

This is obviously assuming that you are using traditional asp.net with viewstate enabled.

Hope this helps.